# How to output bool value to console in Objective C iPhone

Tags: iphone, console, boolean

For an object it is

```
NSLog(@"some object %@", someObject);
```

For decimal it is:

```
NSLog(@"some object %d", 2.33);
```

What is it for a bool?

Comment: `%d` is Not for a decimal, `%lf` is, according to this documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Treat it like an int:

```
NSlog(@"%d",yourBool)
```

... outputs 1 for YES and 0 for NO

If you want to get a YES/NO output use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", (yourBool ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

The reason, copy-pasted from objc.h:

```
#define YES             (BOOL)1
#define NO              (BOOL)0
```

PS: For decimals (floats) it's not %d.... its:

```
NSLog(@"%f",2.33);
```

Comment: Consider using %lf instead, as that is better for doubles than just %f .

Comment: I mostly just go with: `NSLog(yourBool ? @"YES" : @"NO");`